# Why does postgres chose an inefficent resolving of WHERE IN(..)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using an ORM which generates, under certain circumstances, the following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN(1,1,1)
```

As it turns out, postgresql (or rather, postgres' optimizer) does not understand such `IN` queries basically evaluate to `WHERE id = 1` and does a lookup for three rows. You can see this behaviour with the `View Execution Plan` functionality [in this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0ae75/12/0).

This is even the case when all `IN` conditions refer to a non existing entity: [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0ae75/10/0)

Other DBMS like Oracle or MySQL get this right ([Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0ae75/7/0)) so I don't think it is something unachievable.

Obviously, this is something that should be fixed at the orm level, but it got me thinking:

Since Postgresql is generally speaking a pretty good dbms, there is probably a good reason postgres chose to implement the lookup the way they did? Or maybe this isn't as inefficient as it seems when looking at the `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: Because it is not important? BTW: on execution, the condition is short-circuited anyway, (bailing out after the first hit). And: long `IN(..)` lists are a problem anyway.

Comment: Database developers often make the decision to *not* focus on optimizing "trivial" queries that can easily be written "correctly".  There is a bit of a value judgement here, but there is more bang-to-the-buck for making a general `join` algorithm run faster (for instance).

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is? Postgres [uses an index scan](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=66473dd3a2036e78b8a1c8d4c0f18baa) just the way [Oracle does](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d5c008498e048501582b71536aa64e23) But doing performance testing on super-tiny tables isn't really meaningful to begin with.

Comment: It really doesn't matter. Look at these numbers: [Latency Numbers Every Programmer Should Know](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832). When postgreSQL is looking for this record #1 for the first time, it must fetch it from the disk to memory - the time is :10ms (disk seek) + 1ms (read 1MB from disk). The second and third time this record is already in memory - the time is: 0,1ms (100ns - main memory reference) - 100 times faster !!! So - it really doesn;t matter.

Comment: you are "using an ORM which generates, ...". A more pertinent question would be: Why is the ORM generating such poor queries? – Belayer 26 mins ago

Comment: @wildplasser I know it is not important, I just found the why interesting :) 
Also does "the condition is short-circuited anyway" mean postgres won't fetch the same data three times, the optimizer just assumes it has to do it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You're right, the real life table is a lot bigger. I just tried to recreate a minimal example.

Comment: The short-circuit was a bit of a thinko. Of course it only occurs if a match is found. If not, the whole array is traversed. But, the real gain in optimising is in avoiding a nested loop (N^2) if a merge (N) is possible, possibly using indexes.

Answer (score 1):

The fiddle you link to is showing row estimates, not actual row counts.  So you can't tell from that what the database actually does behind the scenes during execution.

If we added code to check the in-list for duplicates, that code would run and take CPU cycles for everyone, even for people who don't write queries which are demented.  That is generally not a trade-off we want to make.

Answer (score 0):

Working with a tiny table is not significant because for very small tables reading the table can be sometimes as fast or faster than using an index.

With a small (but not tiny) table, things work differently:

```
create table test (id integer primary key);
CREATE TABLE

insert into test select generate_series(1,100000);
INSERT 0 100000

explain analyze  select * from test where id in (1, 1, 1);
                                                    QUERY PLAN                  

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on test  (cost=12.90..24.20 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.015
..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (id = ANY ('{1,1,1}'::integer[]))
   Heap Blocks: exact=1
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_pkey  (cost=0.00..12.90 rows=3 width=0) (actual
 time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{1,1,1}'::integer[]))
 Planning Time: 0.218 ms
 Execution Time: 0.061 ms
(7 rows)

analyze test;
ANALYZE

explain analyze  select * from test where id in (1, 1, 1);
                                                      QUERY PLAN                

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using test_pkey on test  (cost=0.29..16.93 rows=3 width=4) (act
ual time=0.017..0.018 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{1,1,1}'::integer[]))
   Heap Fetches: 1
 Planning Time: 0.145 ms
 Execution Time: 0.038 ms
(5 rows)
```

Note also that the plans depend on the fact that ANALYZE has been run or not.

Comment: A more pertinent comment should be linked to the question and not to my answer :-).

Comment: I guess the index only scan is a lot faster than the bitmap heap scan?

Comment: It depends. Here you have 2 plans: (bitmap index scan + bitmap heap scan) vs index only scan; table is small. You would need to check this on a more realistic setup ideally using "real" data.